# How is specific string extracted from given string?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get the tail from a given string which is generated by pwd command.
For example, if pwd command returns:

```
/home/example/src/github.com/abc/def
```

And I want to get string from `github.com` to end.

```
github.com/abc/def
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter expansion in `bash` to achieve what you are looking for. Assuming you have the path as mentioned in `PWD` variable(same as output of `$(pwd)`), you can use the syntax `{str##*}` syntax to get the shortest string from the occurrence of the de-limiter to end of the string. In this case we use multi-character delimiter as `github.com`. Just do

```
printf 'github.com%s' "${PWD##*github.com}"
```

To store it in a new path just use the `-v` syntax provided by `printf`

```
printf -v newvar 'github.com%s' "${PWD##*github.com}"
printf '%s\n' "$newvar"
github.com/abc/def
```

or much simply use without `printf` just as

```
newvar="github.com${PWD##*github.com}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`:

```
pwd | sed 's/.*github.com/github.com/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, with `grep`:

```
pwd | grep -Eo 'github.com.*'
```

Basically: Take `pwd` and only print out the bit including and after github.com

Or, even if you're in a subdirectory of github.com/*/*/ and only want the two bits (author and repo name) after the github.com:

```
pwd | grep -Eo 'github.com/([^/]+/?){2}'
```

which pulls exactly 2 segments after the github.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to get the rest of the string and then combine it with 'github.com' using xargs to get the desired string:

```
pwd | sed 's/^.*github\.com//' | xargs -I {} echo "github.com{}"
```

Output:

```
github.com/abc/def
```

Comment: That's definitely an antipattern!

Comment: First step should be to get a solution that works. To optimize it should be next step.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to start printing content with ANY directory segment that contains a period, you could do the following with awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="/"} /\./ {n=1} n' <<< "/home/example/src/github.com/abc/def"
github.com/abc/def
```

Of course, the same results could be achieved with sed

```
sed 's/.*[^a-z]\([a-z][a-z]*\..*\)/\1/'
```

Or grep alone:

```
egrep -o '[a-z]+\..*'
```